# Annotation-specified bean name conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean def

Tags: spring, repository

I'm having a problem with some Spring bean definitions. I have a couple of context xml files that are being loaded by my main() method, and both of them contain almost exclusively a context:component-scan tag. When my main method starts up, I get this error from Spring:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'converterDAO' for bean class [my.package.InMemoryConverterDaoImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [my.other.package.StaticConverterDAOImpl]
```

Both DAO classes are annotated this way:

```
@Repository("converterDAO")
public class StaticConverterDAOImpl implements ConverterDAO {
...
}
```

The in-memory dao also has the @Repository("converterDAO") annotation. The dao is referenced in other classes like this:

```
...
private @Autowired @Qualifier("converterDAO") ConverterDAO converterDAO;
...
```

I want one DAO to override the definition of the other one, which as I always understood it was one of the principal reasons to use a DI framework in the first place. I've been doing this with xml  definitions for years and never had any problems. But not so with component scans and annotated bean definitions? And what does Spring mean when it says they are not "compatible"? They implement the same interface, and they are autowired into fields that are of that interface type. Why the heck are they not compatible?

Can someone provide me with a way for one annotated, component-scanned bean to override another?

Comment: there is something funny with you second code snippen... please check it.

Comment: Maybe you need to share your main method?

Comment: Please add the actual declaration of converterDAO field. Is it a `ConverterDao` interface or implementation  - it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Oh I see now Boris. Sorry, I was temporarily blind there :-) The field type is the interface ConverterDAO. I fixed the code example.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In an XML file, there is a sequence of declarations, and you may override a previous definition with a newer one. When you use annotations, there is no notion of *before* or *after*. All the beans are at the same level. You defined two beans with the same name, and Spring doesn't know which one it should choose.

Give them a different name (*staticConverterDAO*, *inMemoryConverterDAO* for example), create an alias in the Spring XML file (*theConverterDAO* for example), and use this alias when injecting the converter:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("theConverterDAO")
```

Comment: Why is there no notion of before or after? I have two context files, one is loaded, then the next. In that respect what happens is no different from pure XML definitions. The order is simply the order by which the component-scan instructions are encountered. Beans produced by the second scan override beans produced by the first scan. I hear what you are saying, but I don't understand the logic or technical reason behind it. Also it's not documented and the exception makes no sense at all. Not your fault of course :-) Points for the alias idea. Better than going back to xml definitions.

Comment: Also, regarding the <alias> suggestion, it has the implication that all the different implementations of ConverterDAO will be detected and instantiated by Spring when the context files are loaded. With XML, only the last overriding implementation will be instatiated. This means that all autowired dependencies of all ConverterDAO implementations have to exist, even though only one will ever be used.

Comment: Any strategy to avoid bean name conflict with jar archives ?

Comment: @user1283068 The only possible technical reason I can think of is that the order in which the component-scan instructions are encountered is not guaranteed to be consistent because it's defined by the user. This is different from second overrides first situation you describe since that is presumably documented by whatever tool you would be using.

Answer (score 75):

I had a similar issue with Spring 4.x using @RestController. Two different packages had a class with the same name...

```
package com.x.catalog

@RestController
public class TextureController {
...

package com.x.cms
@RestController
public class TextureController {
...
```

The fix was easy...

```
package com.x.catalog

@RestController("CatalogTextureController")
public class TextureController {
...

package com.x.cms
@RestController("CMSTextureController")
public class TextureController {
...
```

The problem seems to be that the annotation gets autowired and takes the class name by default. Giving it an explicit name in the @RestController annotation allows you to keep the class names.

Comment: Worked for me too with conflicting `@Configuration` classes

Comment: Instead of adding unique bean names in annotations, you can just set `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` as the default bean name generator for your app. With this, all your beans will have fully qualified names(package + class name) instead of just bare class name.

Comment: Note that you really only need to rename one.  That matters if the files are in libraries and you don't want to deal with the whole release process to fix both.

Comment: @BeshEater Do you happen to know why using `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` wouldn't work in Spring Boot 3.2.0? I've also tried writing my own name generator and it failed with the same error as well

Comment: Solution works also for `@Service`, e.g. `@Service("mdcService")` 

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar problem, with two jar libraries (app1 and app2) in one project. The bean "BeanName" is defined in app1 and is extended in app2 and the bean redefined with the same name.

In app1:

```
package com.foo.app1.pkg1;

@Component("BeanName")
public class Class1 { ... }
```

In app2:

```
package com.foo.app2.pkg2;

@Component("BeanName")
public class Class2 extends Class1 { ... }
```

This causes the `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException` exception in the loading of the applicationContext due to the same component bean name.

To solve this problem, in the Spring configuration file `applicationContext.xml`:

```xml
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.app2.pkg2"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.app1.pkg1">
        <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.foo.app1.pkg1.Class1"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

So the Class1 is excluded to be automatically component-scanned and assigned to a bean, avoiding the name conflict.

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar problem, and it was because one of my beans had been moved to another directory recently. I needed to do a "build clean" by deleting the `build/classes/java` directory and the problem went away. (The error message had the two different file paths conflicting with each other, although I knew one should not actually exist anymore.)

Comment: This is especially true with gradle projects where "Build" >> "Rebuild Project" , doesn't really cleans and builds like in visual studio. I had to simply delete the "build" folder from project hierarchy in leftt and then do "Build" >> "Rebuild Project" from intelliJ menu

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. I solved it by using the following steps(Editor: ***IntelliJ***):

1. View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Project. Opens your projects in a
   sub-window.
2. Click on the arrow next to your project.
3. Click on the lifecycle.
4. Click on clean.

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes the problem occurs if you have moved your classes around and it refers to old classes, even if they don't exist.

In this case, just do this :

```
mvn eclipse:clean

mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This worked well for me.

Comment: Well, it happened with me. I moved some stuff around and had the "Build Automatically" unset on Eclipse (facepalm).

Answer (score 4):

If none of the other answers fix your problem and it started occurring after change any configuration direct or indirectly (via git pull / merge / rebase) and your project is a Maven project:

```
mvn clean
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem. I built the project again and the issue was resolved.

The reason is, there are already defined sequences for the Annotation-specified bean names, in a file. When we do a change on that bean name and try to run the application Spring cannot identify which one to pick. That is why it shows this error.

In my case, I removed the previous bean class from the project and added the same bean name to a new bean class. So Spring has the previous definition for the removed bean class in a file and that conflicts with the newly added class while compiling. So if you do a 'build clean', previous definitions for bean classes will be removed and compilation will success.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation internal working on this error**

You are getting this error because after instantiation the container is trying to assign same object to both classes as class name is same irrespective of different packages......thats why error says non compatible bean definition of same name ..

Actually how it works internally is--->>>>.

pkg test1;
….
@RestController
class Test{}

pkg test2;
….
@RestController
class Test{}

First container will get class Test and @RestController indicates it to instantiate as…test = new Test(); and it won’t instantiate twice 
After instantiating container will provide a reference variable test(same as class name) to both the classes and while it provide test reference 
To second class it gets non compatible  bean definition of same name ……

Solution—>>>>

Assign a refrence name to both rest controller so that container won’t instantiate with default name and instantiate saperately for both classes irrespective 
Of same name

For example——>>>

pkg test1;
….
**@RestController(“test1”)**
class Test{}

pkg test2;
….
**@RestController(“test2”)**
class Test{}

**Note**:The same will work with @Controller,@Service,@Repository etc..

**Note**: if you are creating reference variable at class level then you can also annotate it with @Qualifier("specific refrence name") for example 
@Autowired @Qualifier("test1")
Test test;

Comment: This is correct. You cannot have two beans with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on **IntelliJ** after moving an existing file to a new package, solved cleaning caché, when trying to run with maven got that error. I managed solve it with:

`cache:clean`

Comment: Would you be able to specify the full command?

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse, I had moved classes into new packages, and was getting this error.  What worked for me was doing:
*Project > Clean*

and also cleaning my TomCat server by right-clicking on it and selecting *clean*

Answer (score 0):

## Scenario:

I am working on a multi-module Gradle project.

**Modules are:**

```
- core, 
- service,
- geo,
- report,
- util and
- some other modules.
```

So primarily we have prepared a Component[**locationRecommendHttpClientBuilder**] in **geo** module.

## Java Code:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component("locationRecommendHttpClientBuilder")
class LocationRecommendHttpClientBuilder extends PanaromaHttpClientBuilder {
    @Override
    PanaromaHttpClient buildFromConfiguration() {
        this.setURL(PanaromaConf.getInstance().getString("locationrecommend.url"))
        this.setMethod(PanaromaConf.getInstance().getString("locationrecommend.method"))
        this.setProxyHost(PanaromaConf.getInstance().getString("locationrecommend.proxy.host"))
        this.setProxyPort(PanaromaConf.getInstance().getInt("locationrecommend.proxy.port", 0))
        return super.build()
    }
}
```

## application-context.xml

```
<bean id="locationRecommendHttpClient"
      class="au.co.google.panaroma.platform.logic.impl.PanaromaHttpClient"
      scope="singleton" factory-bean="locationRecommendHttpClientBuilder"
      factory-method="buildFromConfiguration" />
```

Then it is decided to add this component in **core** module.

One engineer has previous code for **geo** module and then he has taken the latest module of **core** but he forgot to take the latest **geo** module.

So the component[**locationRecommendHttpClientBuilder**] is double times in his project and he was getting the following error.

> `Caused by:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
>   Annotation-specified bean name 'LocationRecommendHttpClientBuilder'
>   for bean class
>   [au.co.google.app.locationrecommendation.builder.LocationRecommendHttpClientBuilder]
>   conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name
>   and class
>   [au.co.google.panaroma.platform.logic.impl.locationRecommendHttpClientBuilder]`

## Solution Procedure:

After removal the component from **geo** module, component[**locationRecommendHttpClientBuilder**] is only available in **core** module. So there is no conflicting situation. Issue is solved by this way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I imported a two project in the workspace. It created a different jar somehow so we can delete the jars and the class files and build the project again to get the dependencies right.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, issue was with pom.xml
I had dependency added in my application pom.xml for two different packages, which were reflecting to same class name.

Check your pom.xml or annotations which can be the possible injection point for same class.

Answer (score 0):

if you build server with file jar and you use mvn clean install then you change branch with git you have to use command mvn clean either it throw exception as on the article.
key word: mvn clean

Answer (score -1):

Refresh gradle project on Eclipse solved this problem for me