# Persistent ConflictingBeanDefinitionException Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I've created a small maven Spring MVC application in my Eclipse IDE and am continuously getting the following exception when I deploy it

```
ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: 
Annotation-specified bean name 'applicationConfiguration.ApplicationProperties' 
for bean class [com.bofa.rid.config.ApplicationConfiguration$ApplicationProperties] conflicts 
with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [ApplicationConfiguration$ApplicationProperties]
```

`ApplicationConfiguration` was the initial name I gave my single class in the project, so in an attempt to fix the issue I:

- Renamed the file
- Ran Maven Update
- Ran Maven Clean
- Cleaned the project

But I still can't shake the error. Here's my current `AppConfig`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Resource(name="myBean")
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    static class AppProps {
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I don't see `ApplicationConfiguration` defined anywhere in my project. Any ideas on why this might be happening

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801359/annotation-specified-bean-name-conflicts-with-existing-non-compatible-bean-def